# What means stddev of nce_weights on word2vec?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I'm trying to understand how [word2vec](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) example works and don't really understand why set stddev of nce_weights.

```
nce_weights = tf.Variable(
  tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                      stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
```

I tried to remove the stddev parameter and then run it. But couldn't find any differences.

stddev means standard deviation. Why use stddev parameter and what means the stddev value on the example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*nce_weights* are the classifier weights used for implementing the noise-contrastive estimation training technique, an efficient method for training classifiers with a large number of labels (see the explanation in the section "Scaling up with Noise-Contrastive Training" in the [word2vec tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) you originally linked).

These weights will be learned during training, however they first need to be initialized at the beginning of training. We do this by drawing random weights from a truncated normal distribution (a normal distribution with all values within 2 standard deviations of its mean). This is achieved by passing in the [tf.truncated_normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#truncated_normal) op as initializer in the call to [tf.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable). The truncated normal initializer takes as parameters a shape, mean, and standard deviation (see the page linked above for the parameters and their definitions). The last two are the sufficient statistics of the truncated Gaussian distribution that we will be drawing from.

When you don't pass these in (as you mentioned), they simply get initialized to their default values (1.0 in the case of stddev).